Why my batch script fails to execute java program in a loop?
Following batch script is supposed to loop thru files in given directory. Directory contains files with two extensions, which are .in and .out. For example there is a dog.in file and dog.out file. There are multiple such file pairs in that directory. Each file contains only 3-4 lines of text.
Then there is some java program, which is supposed to get a single .out file as an input arg, and a single .in file redirected to stdin using < in java exec command.
The batch script works fine if its a single java exec only, for a single pair of files, like this.
@ECHO OFF
cd e:\WORK\NetBeansProjects\potyczki
pwd
set infname=D:\___Potyczki_Algorytmiczne\2024\mro_tests\mro1k.in
set outfname=D:\___Potyczki_Algorytmiczne\2024\mro_tests\mro1k.out
java -classpath target/classes/ pl.kazanik.potyczki._2024.Mrowki %outfname% < %infname%

When batch script is changed to loop thru files in directory, and exec java program for each pair of files in a loop, then error is thrown telling that Cannot find file given file. The error happens in the batch script, before java program execution starts. This i know because as a first line in main method of java program i have print message, which is not present in the output when batch is executed. There is only above error message, printed for each file pair in directory (so for each iteration of for loop).
@echo off
setlocal
cd e:\WORK\NetBeansProjects\potyczki
pwd
set testdir=D:\___Potyczki_Algorytmiczne\2024\mro_tests
for %%f in (%testdir%\*.in) do (
  set inname=%%f
  call set outname=%%inname:in=out%%
  call java -classpath target/classes/ pl.kazanik.potyczki._2024.Mrowki %%outname%% < %%inname%%
)

Will be grateful for telling what i am doing wrong in the batch script.

Are you using Windows CMD or Unix or Linux or another?  If your problem is happening before the java program executes then the Java tag will not help.  It would be a good idea to look for the right tags to get your question to the right people.  CMD for Windows CMD shell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd as well as others.

Hi i have that script in a .bat file and i execute it inside Windows command line.

@ProgrammersBlock have updated the tags, based on what i saw in other related questions.
Meanwhile have found a solution as well, but as it is basicly my first time batch scripting, its probably not the best

Surely you could just change your for loop to this: For %%G In ("%testdir%\*.in") Do @java.exe -classpath target/classes/ pl.kazanik.potyczki._2024.Mrowki "%%~nG.out" < "%testdir%\%%G", or For %%G In ("%testdir%\*.in") Do @java.exe -classpath target/classes/ pl.kazanik.potyczki._2024.Mrowki "%%~dpnG.out" < "%testdir%\%%G", depending upon your required output location.

I can;t test this, but possibly in your original you may need to escape the < thus: ^< Having said that, your original would also have problems with any filename containing in which is not the extension. @Compo's suggestion is far more robust.

Since noone has provided any answer will provide my solution, which uses delayed variable expansion for variables used inside for loop.
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd e:\WORK\NetBeansProjects\potyczki
pwd
set testdir=D:\___Potyczki_Algorytmiczne\2024\mro_tests
for %%f in (%testdir%\*.in) do (
    set inname=%%f
    call set outname=%%inname:in=out%%
    call java -classpath target/classes/ pl.kazanik.potyczki._2024.Mrowki !outname! < !inname!
)


I provided code for you in the comment section, but received absolutely no feedback from doing so! As for what's above, all I can say is that the only lines in that code which do not require improvement are echo off and ). pwd is not a command built into cmd.exe nor is it a Windows supplied utility, and will therefore generate an error.

tried your code, it failed with error, tried to fix it, but unsuccessful

Provide the error, and I'll adjust my code accordingly. Don't provide it, and I'll blame that error on your mistakes, not my own.
